# Django: using ModelForm to edit existing database entry

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have created a ModelForm class to be able to create and edit database entries. Creating new entries works well, however, i dont know how to use ModelForms to edit/update an existing entry. I can instantiate a ModelForm with a database instance using:

```
form  = MyModelForm(instance=MyModel.objects.get(pk=some_id))
```

However, when i pass this to a template and edit a field and then try to save it, i create a new database entry instead of updating "some_id"?

Edit1:
This is my view

```
def editData(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        editedEntry = form.save() # <-- creates new entry, instead of updating
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Remember you still need to use the `instance` parameter when you instantiate on POST.

```
instance = MyModel.objects.get(whatever)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyModelForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
    ...

else:
    form = MyModelForm(instance=instance)
```

Comment: Ok i was not doing that. So how should i pass my primary key "some_id" to the html template and back again to the view. Should i do it manually as a hidden form field or is there a way to have Django take care of it?

Comment: There's no need to do that. Just use the pattern as I show above.

Comment: But to do this: instance = MyModel.objects.get(whatever),
i need to substitute "whatever" with the primary key "some_id" which i used to create the initial MyModelForm. From where do i get that?

Comment: From the same place you got it from originally, ie the URL.

Answer (score 3):

Also possible and slightly shorter:

```
instance = MyModel.objects.get(whatever)
form = MyModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
...
```