# Django Model form don't update database records

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I am new in django and I want to create a form to update some database entries.

this is a simple form where I have a simple input text where I write the id of the record that I want to update:

main.html

```
<form method='post' action='/config/{{ idprov }}' >
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="idprov" id="idprov" value ="{{ idprov }}" />
<input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Config">
</form>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Proveedor, Estado, Config

class ConfigForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Config
```

this is my views.py:

```
def configView(request,idprov):

    prov = Config.objects.get(idproveedor=idprov)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ConfigForm(request.POST or None, instance=prov)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save(commit=false)
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')
    else:
       form = ConfigForm( instance=prov)
    return render_to_response('config.html',
                              {'form':form})
```

my template config.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<form method='POST' action='' >
   <div class="form-group">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
   </div>
        <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Grabar</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from prov.views import home
from prov.views import proveedores
from prov.views import estado
from prov.views import monitorViewV2

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'prov.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^proveedores/$', 'prov.views.proveedores', name='proveedor'),
    url(r'^estado/$', 'prov.views.estado', name='estado'),
    url(r'^monitor/$', 'prov.views.monitorView', name='monitor'),
    url(r'^monitorv/$', 'prov.views.monitorViewV2', name='monitorv2'),
    url(r'^config/(?P<idprov>\d+)/$', 'prov.views.configView',name='config'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

But I receive the error Page not found.
I try to follow other snippets and always raise different errors.

I think the error is in the urls.py and in the way I pass the argument from the main.html.

Any advice or snippet will be very appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349865/django-using-modelform-to-edit-existing-database-entry) is the answer

Answer (score 2):

First you have a `form.save(commit=false)` in your view without saving it later, thats mean the data is never saved into the model.

Second in your template config.html the form action is empty `<form method='POST' action=''>` change for `<form method='POST' action='.'>`

I hope that help to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the error page not found still persist. I think the error is in the main.html. I am very confused

Comment: What's in your urls.py?