# update database with form in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to save data to the database. I have two tables as shown in the models.py. Every book has several publication. I wish to insert the price of each pub in the form and update thereafter the database. The problem now when I input the price it adds anything on the table `Version`, another point is that at the beginning the user has no book that is at the time that he adds money it creates a book.

**models.py**

```
class book(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='user')
        Price_init = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        Date_creation = models.DateTimeField('date creation')

class version(models.Model):
        date_pub = models.DateTimeField('date pub')
        price = models.IntegerField()
        Dprice = models.IntegerField()
        book = models.ForeignKey(book)
```

my **view.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/view/login/')
def addVersion(request,Book_id):
    response={}
    book1 = book.objects.get(id=book_id)
    class AddForm(forms.Form):
        Price = forms.IntegerField()
    if request.method=='post':
       form=AddForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           try:
                version1 = Version()
                version1.date_pub= datetime.now()
                version1.price=form.cleaned_data['Price']
                version1.book_id= book_id
                version1.Dprice = -(form.cleaned_data['Price'])
                version1.save()
           except:
                xxx=0
           return render_to_response('addVersion.html')
       else:
           form.errors
           return HttpResponse('form invalid')
    else:
        return render(request,'frontend/addVersion.html',response)
    tr.save()
    return render(request,'frontend/addVersion.html',response)
```

addVersion.html

```
<form name="form" method="POST" action="" id="form"> {% csrf_token %}
                        <p style="text-align:center" class="text-error"></p>
                <p style="text-align:center;margin-top:20px"><input id="" name="form" required="required" style="width:100px" value="{{Price}}" type="text"></p>
        <p> <br></p>
```

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349865/django-using-modelform-to-edit-existing-database-entry) is the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Question : 1** The problem now when I input the price it adds anything on the table Version. ?

*Solution :* do form validation correctly

```
bookObj = book.objects.get(id=book_id)
if request.method=='POST':
   form=AddForm(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
      version1 = Version()
      version1.date_pub= datetime.now()
      version1.price = form.cleaned_data['Price']
      version1.book_id = book_id
      version1.Dprice = form.cleaned_data['Price']
      version1.save()
```

**Question : 2**  The beginning the user has no book that is at the time that he adds money it creates a book. ?

Where is the money came from ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer
but I can't see the difference between what I wrote and what you have proposed to me

Comment: I put "post" in uppercase and I had "form invalid" ,do you know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, its "addForm" not "ajouterForm", I copied wrong code, I'll edit it

Comment: it must save just an integer, I will put the javascript it

Comment: Each book has multiple version and each version is characterized by a price, each user has a book, I have a form that contains an input, which will allow the user to enter the price,Dprice is the opposite of price, simply if price =50, Dprice = -50, date_pub , 
it retrieves the date that the user add a version

Comment: @Hayat without book you will get the error when view call `addVersion`

Comment: The more you provide info or edit you question clearly .. more you will get good answer .. ( you know . ?)

Comment: I'm new to django,function addVersion is called just when the book is created, the user will not have the right to access the page addVersion.html' if the book is not created !