# Django 1.8 set exist default value of Update form

Tags: django, forms

I wrote template

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

And, my View is below

```
class UserProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileUpdateForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

And this is my UserProfile model below.
It uses User key

```
  class UserProfile(models.Model):
      # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
      user = models.OneToOneField(User)

      # The additional attributes we wish to include.
      website = models.URLField(blank=True, verbose_name=u'Webサイト')
      picture = models.ImageField(
          upload_to='uploads/profile_images/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True,
          null=True, verbose_name=u'Image'
      )
      age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u'Age')
      country = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name=u'country')
      profile = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name=u'profile')
      address = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name=u'address')
      GENDER_CHOICES = (
          (u'M', u'Male'),
          (u'F', u'Female'),
      )
      gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, verbose_name=u'Gender')
      CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
          (u'U', u'u'),
          (u'R', u'r'),
      )
      category = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, verbose_name=u'category')
      last_accessed = models.DateTimeField()
```

My Form is

```
class UserProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    slug_field = 'user_slug'

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'address', 'profile', 'gender', 'category',
            'age',
            'website', 'picture',
        )
```

But, my form can't fill default value which already set before.

Could you tell me why doesn't set?

Comment: Can you post your model please?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I added my Model

Answer (score -1):

You should look at this: [Django: using ModelForm to edit existing database entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349865/django-using-modelform-to-edit-existing-database-entry)

The key is:

```
form  = MyModelForm(instance=MyModel.objects.get(pk=some_id))
```