# How to prepopulate an Django Update form and write it back to the database

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I'm new at Python & Django and currently struggling right now.
I created an update/edit form with Django Model forms, but it just doesn't prepopulate the form fields and post it to the database at the same time.

I think the problem lies in `form = AdvertForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=form)`.

Without `request.POST or None, request.FILES or None`, it does prepopulate the fields but won't update the data to database.

Here's my `views.py`:

```
def update_advert(request, id):
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return render(request, 'forum/login.html')
else:
    form = get_object_or_404(Advert, pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AdvertForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=form)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('forum:user_account')
    else:
        form = AdvertForm(instance=form) 


    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'forum/update_advert.html', context)
```

In the moment it looks like this, when I try to open the update form:

[opening the form --> not prepopulated :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib0zY.png)

Comment: here is the answer:::: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349865/django-using-modelform-to-edit-existing-database-entry)

Answer (score 2):

According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values, you can use the `initial` attribute when instantiating forms in order to prepropulate your forms.

```
def update_advert(request, id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'forum/login.html')
    else:
        advert_obj = get_object_or_404(Advert, pk=id)


        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AdvertForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=advert_obj)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('forum:user_account')
        else:
            # Prepopulation happens here:
            data = {"some_field": advert_obj.some_val} # Insert all the values of advert_obj here and their field names as keys.
            form = AdvertForm(initial=data) 


        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'forum/update_advert.html', context)
```

In your `AdvertForm`, put this code:

```
class AdvertForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(AdvertForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(AdvertForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.request.user

        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

The overriding `save` method simply does what you were doing in the views to link up the `request.user` to the instance, however I have placed that code in the form class to keep your `views` simple.

Also, I can see one confusing (but not vital) issue - you have mixed up the variable names.
When calling `form = get_object_or_404(Advert, pk=id)`, this should return to a variable name such as `advert` or something similar. Not `form` as that can be confusing as we are returning a model object not a form. Similarly, `form.save(commit=False)` returns an "instance" not a model form. This won't solve your problem but should be pointed out for more clarification on what exactly is being returned and how you should then name your variables.

Comment: Thank you. This really helped me to get a better understanding of my code!
But it still doesn't show the prepopulated fields with **"request.POST or None, request.FILES or None "**...
When I just have it like this: **"form = AdvertForm(instance=advert_obj)"** it will show me prepopulated fields but won't write it back to the database...

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "show"? The code, `form = AdvertForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=advert_obj)` that runs when you make a `POST` request should UPDATE the current `advert_obj`. It wouldn't show those fields again because you are redirecting to `forum:user_account`.

Comment: The `else` clause (when you make a `GET` request), will have the data prepopulated into the form fields as you mentioned. That's working correctly. BUT that part should not save to the database at all because we are just retrieving data. The `POST` request is responsible for saving (in your case, updating the current `advert_obj`)