# ModelForm Fields are not pre-populated with existing data during updating in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I want to update the User and Lab model. I am able to see the form but it is not pre-populated with existing database information even after setting the instance parameter.  If I submit a blank form then all fields are reset to blank values in the database. I have tried several solutions available online but nothing works.

My queries -

1. How do I pre-populate my form with existing data?
2. If the user doesnt fill out a particular field, I want the previous information to be stored as it is and not as a blank value. How do I achieve this?

I have the following models.py

```
class Lab(models.Model):
    uid = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_lab_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Lab.objects.create(uid=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_lab_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.lab.save()
```

Forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(max_length=300)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)

class LabForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lab
        fields = ('company',)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def update_user_details(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        lab_form = LabForm(request.POST,instance=request.user.lab)
        if user_form.is_valid() and lab_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            lab_form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Your profile was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('user_details')
        else:
            messages.error(request,('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        lab_form = LabForm(instance=request.user.lab)
    return render(request, 'update_user_details.html', {'user_form': user_form,'lab_form': lab_form})
```

template -

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% csrf_token %}

<H3> Update Personal information - </H3>
<br>
<form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ user_form.as_p }}
  {{ lab_form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Any help/suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070851/how-to-prepopulate-an-django-update-form-and-write-it-back-to-the-database You can check this, it may help you.

Comment: I tried the solution provided but its still not working!