# Django: Prefill forms with database entries from inside a loop

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I want to prefill a form with already existing database entries but can't access the correct ones.

A user can create a task and pass information on when creating it. When he wants to update it later, the already saved information should be used to prefill the form.

My problem is, that I'm inside a for-loop and it seems that I can't access the elements of the loop.

Here is what I'm doing:

I'm in a template inside a for-loop. The loop lists all tasks with an update button for every task. This button calls a form via the bootstrap data-target. Here's an example:

```
{% for task in tasks %}
    <button class="btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateTask">Update Task</button>   {% endfor %}
```

In my upcoming form I can't use the variables from the task element. For example the task.taskname. However, I can use all other variables like the user.first_name which exists outside the loop.

```
<div class="modal-body">
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'update_task' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Task:</label>
      <input type="text" id="taskID" name="task" class="form-control"  value="{{ user.first_name }}" required> -> this works
      <input type="text" id="taskID2" name="task2" class="form-control"  value="{{ task.taskname }}" required> -> this doesn't         
    </div>                                           
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-block custom-button">
 </div>
```

I know I could do this with opening a completely new page but I want to try to use the data-target calling my view instead of calling the view directly.
Is there any way to pass my currently looped element to the form?

Thanks in advance!

Pascal

Comment: The better way is to pre-fill the info from your forms.py. check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070851/how-to-prepopulate-an-django-update-form-and-write-it-back-to-the-database

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check it out.